# Python method for array with variable dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

This is a simple question, but I couldn't find a 'best practice', and wondered if there was something simpler than lots of if statements. Say I have a method which takes in a variable 'data', which is of shape (N,M), where N can vary. Specifically sometimes data is a 1D array of shape (M,), other times N=100 and data is shape (100,M) for example.

Below is skeleton code of what the method does, for when N>1. How can I adopt this for a general case, when N>1 or N can equal 1 (or preferably when data.shape=(M,), not just (1,M)) ? I can put lots of if statements, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

```
#start with variables data.shape=(N,M), vol.shape=(M,), jstarts and jends .shape=(4,)
N=3
#N=1 #uncomment to test
M=20
jstarts = np.array([0,5,12,15])
jends = np.array([3,10,14,18])
data = np.arange(0,N,M).reshape(N,M)
data_new = np.empty((N,M))

for i in range(0,N):
    for j in range(0,jstarts.size):
        jstart = jstarts[j]
        jend = jends[j]
        tmp = np.sum(data[i,jstart:jend]*vol[jstart:jend])/np.sum(vol[jstart:jend])
        data_new[i,jstart:jend] = tmp
```

*NOTE: jstart and jend depend on j, but don't depend on i

Comment: `for i in range(...): for j in range(...): do_sth()`  is not [idiomatic](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) and numpy's special strength is that is makes operations on [slices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) fast and expressive.

Comment: I simplified the code, and added details. This is simplified from the actual code (jstart and jend are replacements for a complicated np.where()). 
I know range for loops aren't very Pythonic. Maybe I should just refactor. The updated code I think can be done simply with einsum, and if statements for the string based on N==1 or not.

Comment: There's still a nested loop.

Comment: Range for loops are very Pythonic.  It's `numpy` that provides alternatives, usually for things that can be done in parallel.  But some problems are inherently serial.

Comment: Without sample values - `N,M,data,vol,jstart,jend` - I think this question should be closed.  If you want help, make it easy to understand and test.

Comment: @hpaulj -- I added sample values. I guess the important point is that jstarts and jends simply define a range in the M-size dimension, but don't necessarily cover it completely (i.e. some data_new values will be zero).

Comment: Look at `np.atleast_1d`, `...2d`, `3d`.  They help ensure that an array has a certain number of dimensions.  Look also at the code for `hstack` and `vstack` to see how they massage their inputs.

Comment: @hpaulj `for (jstart, jend) in zip(jstarts, jends):` is idiomatic python3; respectively likewise with itertools.izip for python2. where it gets numpyish is what mgilson demonstrated inside the block.

Comment: `zip` and `enumerate` are useful tools, but sometimes simply iterating over a `range()` is clearer.  `python3` `range` is the old `xrange`, clearly a nod towards its comon use in iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've spent a ton of time with numpy, but IIRC, you should be able to drop at least the outer loop by using `Ellipsis`:

```
for j in range(10):
    jstart = jstarts[j]
    jend = jends[j]
    tmp = np.sum(data[...,jstart:jend]*vol[jstart:jend], axis=1)/np.sum(vol[jstart:jend])
    data_new[..., jstart:jend] = tmp
```

Comment: Ah, I knew about the Ellipsis, but didn't realize np.sum() could operate like that (I thought I would have to use einsum). I think this solves the immediate problem, thanks.

Comment: Or, perhaps `len(data.shape) - 1`?

Comment: This actually doesn't work as is, in the original post, the np.sum() produces a single value, which is replicated into the data_new array in indices jstart:jend. With the ellipsis, the tmp should produce a 1d, shape [Nt,1] array, which would then be put into data_new in a space of shape [Nt,jend-jstart+1], so I think I would have to manually replicate the 1d array

Comment: @Michael -- As I said, it's been a while since I've done much with numpy.  Can you `np.sum(data[..., jstart:jend].ravel())`?

Comment: I appreciate the help. The .ravel will only flatten the data and produce a scalar, but really the 1d array that normally results has distinct values and needs to be replicated. I think I just have to bite the bullet and put in an if statement to do tmp=(tmp[np.newaxis,...]).repeat(N,axis=0) if N>1

Comment: @mgilson: I assume jstarts, jends are np.array(..). What about `for (jstart, jend) in zip(jstarts, jends):` ?